# re-rendering html in a div to a new browser window

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I would like to take all my `<div>`'s in a parent `<div>` and re-render the contents into a new broswer window.  Can anyone make any suggestions?  I'm using jQuery and .NET.

1. Get all divs in the markup.

   ```
   var markupData = $("#names").html();
   ```
2. Empty div.

   ```
   $("#names").empty();
   ```
3. open new window displaying markupData.

   ```
   ???
   ```

Comment: Perhaps you can explain the purpose of this exercise... we might have additional insights.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about:

```
var html = $("#names").html();
var my_window = window.open("", "mywindow1", "width=350,height=150");

$(my_window.document).find("body").html(html);
```

Using [`window.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Window.open). Keep a reference to the window you just created and set its HTML.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/A72TH/

---

If you wanted to append a stylesheet containing CSS rules for the blank page, you could write something like this:

```
$(my_window.document)
    .find("head")
    .append("<link rel='stylesheet' href='styles.css' />");
```

Comment: @MdeVera: No problem! See my updated answer if you want to append a `link` element in the `head` of the blank popup page.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to make an instance of a new window and then write to it with your data. Here is a helpful link for that:

http://www.javascripter.net/faq/writingt.htm